# RangeError: Value not in range: on a simple substring command - dart

Tags: flutter, dart, substring

I have a substring command that I want to replace the first 4 digits with a 0 for a cellphone number.

```
final String _cellPhone;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final _cellPhoneShort = '0' '${_cellPhone.substring(4)}';
```

NB This is also what is contained in the current documentation for **string.dart**

````
  /// The substring of this string from [start],inclusive, to [end], exclusive.
  ///
  /// Example:
  /// ```dart
  /// var string = 'dartlang';
  **/// string.substring(1);    // 'artlang'**
  /// string.substring(1, 4); // 'art'
  /// ```
  String substring(int start, [int? end]);
````

Now on hot reload it works perfectly on the emulator however it gives me the following error on the terminal.

What am I possibly missing here?

Thanks.

```
Performing hot reload...                                               /
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following RangeError was thrown building MainBody(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery,
_InheritedProviderScope<AuthBloc>]):
**Value not in range: 4**

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  MainBody file:///E:/Flutter/AndroidStudioProjects/mchana/lib/src/screens/main/top_up.dart:74:15

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _StringBase.substring (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:396:7)
#1      MainBody.build (package:mchana/src/screens/main/top_up.dart:96:47)
#2      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4569:28)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4495:15)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#5      StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#6      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#7      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#8      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#9      StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#11     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#13     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#17     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#19     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5503:32)
#20     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6105:17)
#21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#22     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#23     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#24     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#25     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#27     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#28     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#29     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#30     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#31     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#32     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#33     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#34     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#36     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#38     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#39     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#40     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#42     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#43     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#44     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#45     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#46     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#47     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#48     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#49     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#50     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#51     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#52     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#53     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#54     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#55     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#56     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#57     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#58     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#59     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#60     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#61     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#62     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#63     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#64     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#65     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#66     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#67     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#68     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#69     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#70     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#71     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#72     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#73     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#74     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#75     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#76     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#77     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#78     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#79     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#80     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#81     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#82     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#83     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#84     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#85     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#86     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#87     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#88     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#89     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#90     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#91     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#92     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#93     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#94     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#95     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#96     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#97     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#98     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#99     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#100    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#101    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#102    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#103    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#104    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#105    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#106    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#107    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#108    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#109    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#110    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#111    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#112    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#113    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#114    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#115    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#116    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:181:11)
#117    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#118    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#119    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#120    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#121    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#122    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#123    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#124    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#125    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#126    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#127    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#128    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#129    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#130    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#131    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#132    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#133    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#134    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#135    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#136    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#137    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#138    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#139    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#140    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#141    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#142    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#143    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#144    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4576:5)
#145    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#146    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5981:14)
#147    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#148    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#149    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#150    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#151    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#152    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#153    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#154    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4843:5)
#155    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#156    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#157    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#158    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#159    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#160    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#161    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#162    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#163    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#164    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4699:5)
#165    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3293:15)
#166    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:16)
#167    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)
#168    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4189:5)
#169    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2694:33)
#170    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:873:21)
#171    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:319:5)
#172    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#173    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#174    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:865:7)
(elided 4 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, and dart:async-patch)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
       /
Another exception was thrown: RangeError: Value not in range: 4
```

Comment: What is the value of  `_cellPhone`? Don't guess but check with a debugger or log it before you apply `substring` I strongly suspect its length is < 5, thus `substring(4)` is not valid, because it would start beyond the end of the string

Comment: The length of the _cellPhone is actually 13.

Answer (score 0):

The issue went away after I restarted the emulator and the app from scratch.

NB: the log on *_cellPhone.length* gave me **13** so it wasn't apparent why *_cellPhone.substring(4)* had a value range error.

Also interesting that *_cellPhone.substring(0)* did not have a range error previously & it correctly extracted the first digit. The moment I went with *_cellPhone.substring(1)* and above it produced the range error.

Anyway, a restart 'fixed' the issue.